# Debug Tools in R - stepping through code

Tags: r

This input series works perfectly

```
 Bond.Valuation (bond.id = bondlab10, principal = 1000, price = 100, 
 settlement.date =  "02-4-2013", trade.date = "1-31-2013")
```

This throws an error

```
 Bond.Valuation (bond.id = bondlab10, principal = 1000, price = 100, 
 settlement.date =  "01-5-2013", trade.date = "12-31-2012")

 #Error in Key.Rate.Table[x, 3] = (spotrates("ns", BetaVector, m = Key.Rate.Table[x, 
    : replacement has length zero.
```

I am trying to use debug tools to step through the code but I am not having much luck. I get the following when I debug

```
debug at <tmp>#29: Bond.Term.Structure <<- Key.Rate.Analysis(bond.id = bondlab10, 
Rate.Delta = Rate.Delta, BetaVector = BetaVector, principal = principal, 
price = price, cashflow = Bond.CashFlow)
```

I know the function and the line but I have no idea what is wrong from the messages.  Advise on debugging is appreciated.  Basically, I have a long settlement here but this will be required for mortgage backed securities.

-Update, I found the problem but not from the debugger.  Is there a way to watch R step through each calculation and see values?

Comment: I havent personally tried it, but there's been a lot of talk about RStudio's debugging setup.  Google can help you there

Comment: In general, if you are debugging a function, and it in turn calls another function, simply debug that next one as well. ie, when you were at line `29` above, instead of hitting `c/Enter`, you would write `debug(Key.Rate.Analysis)`  You can also use `debugonce` in place of debug

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, [Revolution R](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/) has good support for step-by-step debugging. It provides a Visual-Studio-style interface to R, with breakpoints and mouseovers on values of variables.

The academic version is free.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest [R-studio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/) has built-in debugger. The community edition is free.